# Spritely, change picture by direction

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, direction

I am trying to animate swimming fish in Spritely plugin.

```
var lastX = 0;
var count = 0;
$('#fish1').sprite(
{
    fps: 2, 
    no_of_frames: 1,
    on_first_frame: function(obj) 
    {
        count++;
        if (count > 4)
        {
            if (lastX < obj.position.left) 
            {
                obj.fps(2).spState(1);                                      
            }
            else 
            {
                obj.fps(2).spState(2);
            }
            lastX = obj.position.left;
            count = 0;
        }                   
    }
})
.spRandom(
{
    top: 0, 
    bottom: $(document).height()-308, 
    left: 0, 
    right: $(document).width()-498, speed: 10000
});
```

This is definition of my fish. Can someone tell me, how detect direction of random move? My solution apply when is set first frame, where I last X position with fish position.

But this don't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: is there a typo with `obj.position.lef`?

Comment: sorry, here is only mistake with copy. Originaly I have there missing T.

Comment: Does this question still need answering?

Comment: Yes.  I would like the answer.

Comment: I pretty sure you don't need this anymore, but here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055175/change-spstate-when-direction-change-in-sprandom/17055827#17055827)